# Общедоступная папка в сети интернет

Tags: ubuntu, share, samba

Есть сервер на Ubutu 16.04
Сделал на нём общедоступную папку, пробросил 445 порт на роутере. В локальной сети папка видна.
Каким образом можно сделать её общедоступной в интернет?
IP статичный, доменное имя привязано.
Web-сервис так же доступен, сайт открывается с любого устройства.

Comment: ssh вот что Вам нужно. Инструкцию писать не буду интернет кишит этим. Еще возможно вам стоит посмотреть на sshfs( но это не точная информация(= )

Comment: Не, я конечно понимаю все ваши рекомендации, SSH, FTP... Вопрос заключается в другом: каким образом можно сделать папку общедоступной в интернет? Чтобы я в файловом менеджере по ip получил к ней доступ. Вопрос конкретный, не требующий дополнительной информации.

Comment: Файловый менеджер какой ОС?

Comment: Windows, порт открыл 445, по LAN папка доступна ив под любой ОС

Comment: Я немножечко не сис админ... Но на сколько я знаю, так сделать нельзя... однако решение раз - ssh там или ftp и поставить вспомогательную прогу на windows например filezilla, решение 2 sshfs, так же прийдется поставить вспомогательную программу но для пользователя будет просто папка в этом случае, доступная из проводника

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, так лучше не делать, потому как самба не предназначена для работы через интернет - трафик не шифруется (все будут знать, что вы передаете и смогут подменять передаваемое), подвержен атакам (что-то там про пайпы и RCE) и так далее.

Чтобы делать шаровую папку у себя, используйте owncloud и подобные частные облака.

Comment: Так мне и нужно так сделать. Мне общая папка нужна, для общего доступа.

Comment: Вы собираетесь использовать неверный инструмент - то, что перечислил я -это примеры злоумышленного воздействия на ресурс, причем осуществлять это будут не люди, а автоматические программы. Поставьте уже owncloud

Comment: Я понимаю. Мне нужно понять механизм, как это сделать.

Comment: За owncloud отдельно спасибо, не слышал о нем:)

Answer (score 2):

Для вас лучшим вариантом будет в такой ситуации использовать верный инструмент, попробуйте использовать [FTP Server](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE_ubuntu_server/%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0/ftp_server).